# Find the matrix of the transformation with respect to the basis $\cos(t),\sin(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

> Let $V$ be the space spanned by the two functions $\cos(t),\sin(t)$.
>   Find the matrix of the given transformation $T$ with respect to the
>   basis $\cos(t),\sin(t)$, and determine whether $T$ is an isomorphism.

$T(f(t))=f(\frac{t-\pi}{4})$

I tried to evaluate:

$T(\cos(t))=\cos(\frac{t-\pi}{4})$

and

$T(\sin(t))=\sin(\frac{t-\pi}{4})$

But I'm honestly not sure how to. I tried to use Wolfram to find equivalence that will help me create the matrix of the transformation, but there wasn't any helpful equivalences that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help
\begin{align}
\cos(x - a) &= \cos(a)\cos(x) + \sin(a)\sin(x)\\
\sin(x - a) &= \sin(a)\cos(x) - \sin(x)\cos(a)
\end{align}
You will have $a = \frac{-\pi}{4}$ which is easy to evaluate.